# Why does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^n}{n!} = e^\pi$?

Tags: summation, pi, constants

Why is it that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^n}{n!} = e^\pi \quad ?$$

I think it has to do with the gamma function, but I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: What is $x$ in your equation?

Comment: $x$ is often used to indicate a real variable, in which case it's unclear what $\sum_{n=0}^x\frac{\pi^n}{n!}$ is supposed to mean. Be as it may, we could argue that, since $e^\pi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\pi^n}{n!}$, by all means $\sum_{n=0}^x \frac{\pi^n}{n!}$ should be strictly smaller than $e^\pi$.

Comment: Well $f(x)=e^x$ is often defined as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$ so this just $f(\pi)$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Only if we first let $x \to \infty$ in OP's question and then replace $\pi$ with a (different?) $x$. OP's claim as stated is definitely untrue without the limit (how could the right-hand side even be independent of $x$?).

Comment: @PrincessEev it didn't make much sense the way it's written  I went with a naïve interpretation. I try to err on the side of understanding.

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding I meant that when x approaches infinity then $\sum_{n = 0}^{x}\frac{{}\pi ^{n}}{n!}$ approaches e^π (I edited my original question)

Answer (score 1):

Why does? It actually doesn't. That would be true if you had the infinite series:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\pi^n}{n!} = e^{\pi}$$

Yet your sum is finite, and we have in general:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^M \dfrac{a^n}{n!} = \frac{e^a \Gamma (M+1,a)}{M!}$$

Where $\Gamma(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the incomplete Euler Gamma function.

Comment: Oh that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

It is just the exponential series: Since $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^n \over n!}=\exp(x),$$ replacing $x$ with $\pi$ delivers the desired equation.